# I am changing width and height of a view on a button click but i want to switch to default view on 2nd click

Tags: android, button, view

I making a camera mirror app i set up a button click that makes the texture width and height as given by me but i want also to go back to default width and size on the 2nd click on the same button... can any one help how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? could you please post some code?

Comment: I have not tried anything just used getLayoutparams to set height and width but i have no idea how to go back to my previous height and width? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can store the initial height and width of the button in some variable and on the click after change you can set the height and width using the variable.

Comment: If you feel this is the right answer please mark it as the right answer @Muhammad Umer